# Movement of div causing a glitch

Tags: html, css

I have a submenu that becomes visible when hovered on a nav element.When the element is no longer hovered on, the submenu is goes invisible and moves up. I have attached part of my code below.The problem I am facing is,since the submenu is right below the nav element, the upward movement is making the submenu active during the transition and thereby causing it to glitch. How do I fix this

```css
#sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 13.2rem;
  right: 54%;
  top: 3.9%;
  height: 330%;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 600;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.1s ease;
}

#nav>li:hover #sub-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  top: 7.9%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <nav>
    <ul id="nav">
      <li>
        <a>Test1</a>
        <ul id="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="">Test2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: You could add `#nav>li { position:relative; }` to prevent the sub-menu from overlapping. Or use `#sub-menu { pointer-events: none }` to prevent the mouse from interacting with the sub-menu. Or transition the min-height value rather than the top value. `#sub-menu { transition: 0.1s ease; }` targets all css-rules for a given selector and can be made more specific by targetting individual rules: `transition: min-height 2s`. What animation/effect are you aiming to produce?

Comment: hey, I already have  nav position as a relative. I can't use pointer-events as none because I need to interact with the submenu. The animation I'm trying to achieve is submenu dropping down